# Create option to flag an audit

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, vote-to-close, review-audits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4250809

I can understand how this turned out to be a useful question. On the other hand, by what I understand to be guidelines of what makes a question worthwhile, OP

1. didn't seem to make any effort or do research of his own
2. was rather vague
3. this is in fact and title a "how to" question.

On the other hand, the question DID get 9 upvotes and NO down-votes. So I admit, I could be wrong.

Still, I feel this audit is at least misleading. Here again, Others may disagree.

But, I would like to have an option besides ***"I Understand"***.

**Because I don't understand, and at present I don't agree.**

I'd like to see a 2nd button like ***"I Disagree"***. While I may be wrong about this audit question being bad/misleading (good luck convincing me), but I feel that there should be a way to flag / challenge audit questions.

---

**P.S.**, the audit question I'm pointing to is less important than the idea that I would like to be able to challenge them. I understand that making a good audit is hard and they're not perfect. That's why it benefits everyone to make the audits review-able.

---

**P.P.S.**, please don't close this. Vote it up. The "original" that this is duplicate of is almost a year old. **Time for this request to be made again.** and again. and again.

For now, I'm going on close-review strike. AGAIN.

Comment: I found this audit a difficult one. If I were you, I'd downvote it as "made no effort" **since** I don't know much about iOS development. But looking from the answer, looks like it is the first question of its kind, and many viewers find it very useful, albeit little effort (probably also due to no official documentation?). As for your request, you can read more on the dupe.

Comment: @AndrewT., this may have been a worthwhile Q, but it wasnt a good audit

Comment: @hichris123, this is indeed a duplicate. But since the original post is almost a year old, I'd say it's time to make this request again. Meta, as I understand it, is not like SO. It's to debate what's good for SO. **If the original feature request is being ignored, I'd like to request it again.**